# sublime text: how to go to previous position in the same file

Tags: sublimetext3

In sublime text, I can see using `Alt -` takes to previous cursor position.

But it also takes to other files. I want to go to previous cursor position in the current file only.

What can be done for this

Comment: The classes and functions related to the jump history and jumping are all defined in `Packages/Default/history_list.py` if you'd like to take a look at how they're implemented. It shouldn't be too difficult to refactor the jump commands to only look at the current view instead of all views in the current window.